# R: Analyzing whether accounts receivable is recurring over time

Tags: r

I am trying to find accounts/customers that deliver recurring invoices within a time series dataset. The sample input is as follow:

```
yearmonth <- c("2019-11", "2019-11", "2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05")
receivables <- c("Cust A", "Cust B", "Cust A", "Cust A", "Cust B", "Cust C", "Cust A", "Cust B", "Cust D", "Cust E")
category_group_name <- c("Expense", "Expense", "Expense", "Expense", "Expense", "Expense","Expense", "Expense","Expense","Expense")
```

Now what I would like to create, is a mutated category_group_name, in which the recurring invoices are classified as "Fixed Expense", and one time invoices as "Variable Expense".

I am getting a bit stuck here, is there anyone that could help?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is your data for that? How would we know what is recurring invoices and and one time invoices.

Comment: For example, if you see "Cust A" in both 2019-11 and 2020-03, it can be considered as a recurring invoice

Comment: So if a customer is present more than once in the table, then that customer is recurring?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Have posted my code, see if that works:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer:

```
> dat %>% group_by(receivables) %>% mutate(recurring = n()) %>% mutate(category_group_name = case_when(recurring > 1 ~ "Fixed Expense", TRUE ~ "Variable Expense")) %>% select(-recurring)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   receivables [5]
   yearmonth receivables category_group_name
   <chr>     <chr>       <chr>              
 1 2019-11   Cust A      Fixed Expense      
 2 2019-11   Cust B      Fixed Expense      
 3 2019-12   Cust A      Fixed Expense      
 4 2020-01   Cust A      Fixed Expense      
 5 2020-02   Cust B      Fixed Expense      
 6 2020-02   Cust C      Variable Expense   
 7 2020-03   Cust A      Fixed Expense      
 8 2020-03   Cust B      Fixed Expense      
 9 2020-04   Cust D      Variable Expense   
10 2020-05   Cust E      Variable Expense   
>
```

Data used:

```
> dat
   yearmonth receivables category_group_name
1    2019-11      Cust A             Expense
2    2019-11      Cust B             Expense
3    2019-12      Cust A             Expense
4    2020-01      Cust A             Expense
5    2020-02      Cust B             Expense
6    2020-02      Cust C             Expense
7    2020-03      Cust A             Expense
8    2020-03      Cust B             Expense
9    2020-04      Cust D             Expense
10   2020-05      Cust E             Expense
> dput(dat)
structure(list(yearmonth = c("2019-11", "2019-11", "2019-12", 
"2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-03", "2020-04", 
"2020-05"), receivables = c("Cust A", "Cust B", "Cust A", "Cust A", 
"Cust B", "Cust C", "Cust A", "Cust B", "Cust D", "Cust E"), 
    category_group_name = c("Expense", "Expense", "Expense", 
    "Expense", "Expense", "Expense", "Expense", "Expense", "Expense", 
    "Expense")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
>
```